# Multiplying target values with a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
X = ['M','W','W','M','M','W']
NUM = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

trying to write a subroutine that will take NUM list and depending on whether the value in the corresponding list is M  or W  will multiply the value from Num list by either 5 when M is present and 10 with W.

have tried using two target values and index numbers with little success

Comment: Include what you have tried, please.

Comment: fun: `[n*[5, 10][m == 'W'] for n,m in zip(NUM, X)]`

Comment: @timgeb, can you explain the long version of [n * [5, 10][m == 'W']?  Cleanest answer but it's not the most readable for me.  I could use a new trick.

Comment: @dreamzboy it's pretty hacky, clean would be `[n*5 if m == 'N' else n*10 for ...]`. Anyway, `[m == 'W']` is `[True]` or `[False]` and treated as `[1]` or `[0]` when indexing into `[5, 10]`.

Comment: @timgeb, thanks for the explanation.  I've never seen your syntax before but good to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would do what you want:

```
X = ['M', 'W', 'W', 'M', 'M', 'W']
NUM = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
X_VAL = {'M': 5,
         'W': 10
         }
result = []
for index, val in enumerate(NUM):
    result.append(val * X_VAL[X[index]])

print(result)
```

Let me know if you need any help understanding the code.

EDIT:
Like @user2357112 said you can `zip` both lists like this:

```
X = ['M', 'W', 'W', 'M', 'M', 'W']
NUM = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
X_VAL = {'M': 5,
         'W': 10
         }
result = []
for val, x in zip(NUM, X):
    result.append(val * X_VAL[x])

print(result)
```

Comment: It'd be simpler to `zip` the sequences instead of `enumerate`-ing one.

Comment: No problem! Mark the answer as correct if it solved your issue ;-)

Comment: If the first list contained a letter and a number such as  x = M1,W2 would it make a difference to the outcome of the code?

Comment: I don't think so. As far as you have some mechanism like the dict I added `X_VAL`, the dict keys are strings so it doesn't matter if it's `'M': 5` or `'M1': 5`.

Answer (score 1):

Using a simple list comprehension and Python's ternary operator:

```
X = ['M','W','W','M','M','W']
NUM = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

final = [i * (5 if j == 'M' else 10) for i, j in zip(NUM, X)]
print(final)
```

Output:

```
[5, 20, 30, 20, 25, 60]
```

If you had more than two letters, and a unique multiplication value for each one, you could use a dictionary:

```
>>> X = ['M','W','W','M','M','W', 'K', 'J', 'J', 'L']
>>> NUM = [1,2,3,4,5,6,4,2,1,8]
>>> dct = {'M': 5, 'W': 10, 'J': 8, 'K': 4, 'L': 3}
>>> [i * dct[j] for i, j in zip(NUM, X)]
[5, 20, 30, 20, 25, 60, 16, 16, 8, 24]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to use `lambda` functions and `map`:

```
def mult(x, num):
    factor = lambda i: 5 if i=='M' else 10
    return list(map(lambda i: factor(i[0]) * i[1],zip(x,num)))

X = ['M','W','W','M','M','W']
NUM = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

print(mult(X, NUM))
```

Output:

```
[5, 20, 30, 20, 25, 60]
```